# Autocomplete after three letter search from database using materializecss chips

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var surgeonList = {};
surgeonList['John'] = null;             
surgeonList['Jack'] = null;             
surgeonList['Jim'] = null;

$('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
    autocompleteOptions: {
      data: surgeonList,
      limit: Infinity,
      minLength: 3,
      delay: 1000,
      appendTo: "#someElem",
      noItem : 'no data found'
    }      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <div class="chips chips-autocomplete no-autoinit chips-placeholder" id="surgeon">               </div>               <label class="active" for="surgeon">NPI/Surgeon</label>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I need help in showing the suggestions on materialize chips option. Currently it is showing suggestions only if the data is loaded initially using `$('.chips-autocomplete').chips()` method. But my requirement is not to load all data initially, only when user types three letters on the chip it should go to database and fetch the related data using like search and display it on the suggestions/autocomplete.

Below is my html code

```
<div class="chips chips-autocomplete" id="surgeon" ></div>
```

I have the following code

```
$('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
    autocompleteOptions: {
      function :$scope.typeSurgeon(),
      data: $scope.surgeonList,
      limit: Infinity,
      minLength: 3,
      delay: 1000,
      appendTo: "#someElem",
      noItem : 'no data found'
    }      });
```

Comment: Please fix your code. You can also use SO code snippets. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: For what you are trying to accomplish I would look into something called debounce.  This allows you to set a delay after the user has stopped typing to fetch data from the database.